# Login script not redirecting correctly when session already present.

Tags: php, session, redirect

Having a little problem here , its kinda hard to explain so bear with me.

Background: Database has an offer column with a default value of “1”. Upon login the user is redirected according to the value in the offer column. (So on first login user is redirected to example.com/offer1 , after offer 1 is completed this value is updated so on next login user is redirected to offer 2 – in essence storing the users progress) All of this and the different script that updates the values is working fine.

Here’s the part of the script that redirects according to the offer value:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';
```

This works fine in redirecting when a session is not already present and the user logs in from scratch (this part of script)

```
<?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />'; 

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
```

However here’s the problem, if there is already a session present , there is an error in redirecting (Not Found: The requested URL /'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'/' was not found on this server.Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.)

Here’s this part of the script that’s causing the issue– I think there’s a formatting error somewhere here but I tried everything and cannot seem to correct it.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
     ?>
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';


  <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    </ul>

<?php
```

And here’s the full script incase it helps.

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>Login)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">
<?php

if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
     ?>
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';


  <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

         echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />'; 

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    ?>

   <h1>Member Login</h1>

   <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

   <?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much & hope that this makes sense.

Comment: you have declared `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />` in body tag try putting that in head

Comment: Your PHP closing tag `?>` is before the `echo`, it should be after.

Comment: Thanks @caCtus Sadly still isn't working however :( , now redirecting to example.com/offer rather than getting the value from the database and redirecting (e.g. to example.com/offer1)

Answer (score 1):

caCtus is right,
try switching the lines

```
 ?>
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';
```

to

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';
 ?>
```

### Another try

Is $row available in the code while not logging in?
Try to add this:

```
$_SESSION['offer'] = row['offer'];
```

to the login-script.

And change the line after logged in to:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$_SESSION['offer'].'\'" />';
```

Comment: Thanks, swapped the lines. Sadly still isn't working :( , redirecting to example.com/offer  rather than getting the value from the database and redirecting (e.g. to example.com/offer1)

Answer (score 0):

This your code (I kept only what interests us here) :

```
  if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />';

    /**
    * $row is empty here! You didn't make any mysql_query to get its value.
    **/

  } elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1) {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);

         echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />'; 

    }
}
```

In the first `if` statement, try this :

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

    $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($user) > 0) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($user);
      echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'http://example.com/offer'.$row['offer'].'\'" />'; 
    }
  }
```

Also, rather than add an HTML element to make a redirection, you should use the PHP [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.
Keep in mind that `mysql_query()` is deprecated and that you should use another option (you'll find documentation on the PHP website and probably many informations on StackOverflow or other websites).